# Including a gedcom within a gedcom

Tags: gedcom

I have a large gedcom which I am wish to break into several different gedcoms. For example, I am trying to break out my half sisters tree and my tree into separate gedcoms. We have a common father, different mother. I would like to have a gedcom of my father which can be referenced by my gedcom and my sisters gedcom. Simply copying entries from my tree into my sisters tree is an unreliable solution. If something changes in our common father's tree, my tree and my sister's would require separate editing violating a basic principle of data integrity: **don't have same data in more than one place**.

Comment: To get a good answer to this question you need to explain what you wish to do with the split gedcoms. If it is just to view one particular line then that can be done without splitting. If, however, you want to share just one part of your gedcom that would be a different solution. Explain what you want to achieve.

Comment: The basic issue for me here is that you have given us a "solution" (split the files with no duplication) but we have no idea what the underlying requirements are. If the requirement is to reduce file size, that's one thing. If the requirement is to allow you and your sister to work independently, at the same time, that's another.

Comment: No data duplication is an admirable principle by the way.

Comment: AdrianB38 , more than an admirable principle.  Non duplication of data is a bedrock principle of data integrity .  Data integrity is what I am looking for..  Thank you for taking time to consider my question.

Comment: Although my objective is totally irrelevant to my rather specific question, I will more completely explain what I am trying to do.  I plan to create a Badagliacca Family website.  One feature will allow submission of family trees, as known by submitters/  I would like to "stitch" these trees together as appropriate. I did give another example in my question.  Best regards to all.

Answer (score 3):

There is no mechanism within GEDCOM 5.x to refer to another GEDCOM file in such a fashion that it is possible to process individuals, sources etc within that other file in an "intelligent" fashion. Some GEDCOM manipulating software will allow reference to external files in a manner which is always problematic since the GEDCOM standard isn't good at defining such links usefully. However, I know of no software that will interpret the target file as a GEDCOM - that doesn't mean that there isn't any such software, just that I don't know of any, and that such an interpretation is outside the GEDCOM standard.